# xUnit throws System.MissingMethodException when calling handler (MediatR)

Tags: asp.net-core, moq, xunit, cqrs, mediatr

I have an .NET Core v2.1. API with CQRS. To simplify the controller, i'm using MediatR.
Now i'm trying to write some unit tests for my handlers with xUnit, but it's throwing this exception:

> StackTrace do Resultado:   at
> Research.Application.EventoContext.Commands.ConfirmarPresencaCommandHandler.Handle(ConfirmarPresensaCommand
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&
> stateMachine)    at
> Research.Application.EventoContext.Commands.ConfirmarPresencaCommandHandler.Handle(ConfirmarPresensaCommand
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Research.Application.EventoContext.Commands.ConfirmarPresencaCommandHandler.Handle()
> in
> C:\Users\public\Desktop\Research\ResearchAPI\app\src\Research.Teste\Commands\EventoCommands.cs:line
> 38
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- Mensagem do Resultado:   System.MissingMethodException :
> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> MediatR.IMediator.Send(MediatR.IRequest`1<!!0>,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.

This is my command and handler. Since I don't have repositories, I created a data context interface with DbSets and the SaveChangeAsync() method:

```
public class ConfirmarPresensaCommand : IRequest<PontuacaoVM>
{
    public Guid id_usuario { get; set; }
    public Guid id_evento { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> sub_eventos { get; set; }
}

public class ConfirmarPresensaCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<ConfirmarPresensaCommand, PontuacaoVM>
{
    private readonly IMySqlContext _context;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public ConfirmarPresensaCommandHandler(IMySqlContext context, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public async Task<PontuacaoVM> Handle(ConfirmarPresensaCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var _presenca = await _context.PresencasUsuarios
                                      .Include(p => p.SubEvento)
                                      .Where(p => p.CodigoUsuario == request.id_usuario &&
                                                  p.SubEvento.CodigoEvento == request.id_evento)
                                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (_presenca == null)
        {
            var _subEvento = await _context.SubEventos
                                           .Where(s => s.CodigoEvento == request.id_evento &&
                                                       s.Principal)
                                           .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            await _context.PresencasUsuarios.AddAsync(new PresencaUsuario
            {
                CodigoUsuario = request.id_usuario,
                CodigoSubEvento = _subEvento.Codigo,
            }, cancellationToken);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        return await _mediator.Send(new GerarPontuacaoCommand(request.id_usuario, "Evento", "Confirmar"));
    }
}
```

And this is my test. I'm using Moq.EntityFrameworkCore v2.0.1:

```
public class ConfirmarEventoTeste : TesteUtils
{
    public Mock<IMySqlContext> _moqContext;
    public Mock<IMediator> _moqMediator;
    
    public ConfirmarEventoTeste()
    {
        _moqContext = new Mock<IMySqlContext>();
        _moqMediator = new Mock<IMediator>();

        _moqMediator.Setup(m => m.Send(It.IsAny<ConfirmarPresencaCommand>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()).ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<PontuacaoVM>());
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ConfirmarPresenca_Sucesso()
    {
        var _command = new ConfirmarPresensaCommand();
        var _handler = new ConfirmarPresensaCommandHandler(_moqContext.Object, _moqMediator.Object);

        var _result = await _handler.Handle(_command, new CancellationToken());

        Assert.NotNull(_result);
    }
}
```

I know I need to write the setups for the unit test works, but for now my concern it's that the Handle() call on the test is not even hiting my Handler.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you need to **mock** `Send` mehod in `MediatR`

```
_mediatorMock = new Mock<IMediator>();
_mediatorMock.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<GerarPontuacaoCommand>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Also, this might be help you [Mocking MediatR 3 with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249816/mocking-mediatr-3-with-moq)

But I will be prefer another method of testing for `MediatR`. I will be prefer `integration tests`. Because with `integration tests` you can check correct behaviour of this package. Also, this approach use developers to tests behaviour in official examples in [github](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/test/MediatR.Tests/SendTests.cs).

They do the following steps *(common algorithm)*:

1. Create instance of `Dependency injection` container
2. Register your handlers
3. Get instance of `IMediator`
4. Using `Send` method to send request
5. Finally, check response `Message`

#### Dependency injection from Microsoft

If you use common DI from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection), do the following steps:

1. Create instance of DI container

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
```

2. Register handlers using [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/)

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(CustomerLoginRequest).Assembly);
```

3. Build `service provider` in the last moment after all dependencies was added

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

4. Get meditor service from DI

```
var mediator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
```

5. Put your `mediator` to your handler class and execute it.
6. Also, `Assert` the result.

#### Dependency injection from other package

If you use another package for DI - you can check example in [github](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/test/MediatR.Tests/SendTests.cs) repository and create own test by example. They use [StructureMap](https://structuremap.github.io/) for DI.

Comment: I've tried both approaches, still no luck. When I eliminate the internal mediator and call the handler directly it works just fine. But still not able to test controllers, for example, because of the MediatR.

Comment: Did you create DI Container and inject `MediatR` in your `Controllers`?