# How to create MSTest method for Mediatr

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mstest

I'm trying to create MSTest method for .NET Core application.
Inside the test method I'm trying to call .net core controller's parameterized constructor. The constructor has mediatr parameter.
How do I pass value for the mediatr from MSTest method to .NET Core constructor?

Comment: Does this question help? [Mocking MediatR 3 with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249816/mocking-mediatr-3-with-moq)

Answer (score 0):

> var mediator = new Mediator(Mock.Of());